How do I get packets to egress to the tap0 interface rather than the lo interface?
I ran ping 10.0.0.1 and ping -I tap0 10.0.0.1 to see if my custom tcp/ip stack would receive them.
Instead of sending the packets through the tap0 interface, they are sent  through the loopback. I  confirmed with tcpdump -i any icmp reports all icmp packets sent go through lo.
What would cause this ?
How do I fix it?
Output of ip route and ifconfig:
10.0.0.0/24 dev tap0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.1

--- 

tap0: flags=4419<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 0.0.0.0
        inet6 fe80::d82c:11ff:fe95:b10d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 82:6d:32:1e:98:bb  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 284  bytes 32806 (32.0 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0


If you ping the local machine it is loopback traffic no matter what IP. What is your actual problem that you're trying to diagnose using ping?

Im trying to test out my icmp implementation, which is listening on a tap. What I dont understand is how do I get the traffic to go through the tap interface rather than the lo interface

...don't use local traffic? Have a VM that sends traffic to you or similar.

I dont see why its not possible to do it like this all locally/on the same os? My tcp/ip stack im developing is all running locally and so is the interface so why is it not possible to do it like this?

Because - as you have discovered - the kernel bypasses several parts of the networking stack for traffic it believes is destined for the local computer.

I see, how come then if i do something like 10.0.0.2 it doesnt have the same behavior? Instead it goes through the tap0 as I would like 10.0.0.1 to do. Also how come the same happens if I do ping -I tap0 127.0.0.1? Shouldnt the kernel send that to the lo interface since thats a local ip? Instead
